# How to avoid inserting new lines before joins, table names and 'ON' condition in SQL editor in PhpStorm

Tags: sql, phpstorm, autoformatting

How to avoid inserting new lines before joins, table names and 'ON' condition in SQL editor in PhpStorm (2018.1) (autoformatting, Ctrl+Alt+L):

```
"...
FROM
  table1 table1_alias <here>
  INNER JOIN <here>
  table_2 table2_alias <and here>
    ON table1_alias.field1 = table2_alias.field1
..."
```

Comment: Check Code Style for SQL --- `Settings (Preferences on macOS) |  Editor | Code Style | SQL --> Queries`

Comment: @LazyOne I don't seem to have the "-->Queries" tab: [link](https://i.postimg.cc/15pMt0d1/sql.jpg)

in advised Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Code Style | SQL --> Queries. There are 2 metntions of the 'join' word in the 'General' tab, but they seem to be irrelevant for my case

Comment: What's your IDE version? I have that on my **2018.2.6** -- https://postimg.cc/R6VtS42v

Comment: Ah, it's 2018.1.2

Comment: Get latest stable **2018.3.x** (or even an EAP build of 2019.1) and see if it works there for you (IDE will use separate IDE-wide settings so can be run in parallel to your current version; as long as you do not work on the same project, obviously .. as project settings are project specific). If all good -- consider upgrading.